# overloading operator++ for a pointer

Tags: c++

i need to loop through a memory region which contains my own defined types:

```
struct ModuleList 
{
    char ModuleName[64];
    int32_t NumberOfFunctions;

};

struct FunctionList
{
    char FunctionName[64];
    DWORD FunctionAddress;
};
```

These lays out in memory like this:

```
0: ModuleList[0]
0 + sizeof(ModuleList): FunctionsList[NumberOfFunctions]
0 + sizeof(ModuleList)+ NumberOfFunctions * sizeof(FunctionList): ModuleList[1]
.
.
.
```

What i want to do is, overloading operator ++ for ModuleList* so i can easily increment my pointer correctly, because default ++ operator for pointer only increments for sizeof(ModuleList) and i want to increment for sizeof(ModuleList)  and size of functions (which is NumberOfFunctions * sizeof(FunctionList)). These structs in memory are completely dynamic, which my program gets over the network.
Currently, i am doing this:

```
unsigned short ModuleCount = 0;
BYTE* pTemp = (BYTE*)MemoryAdr;
for (; std::string(((ModuleList*)(pTemp))->ModuleName).find(".dll") != std::string::npos; pTemp += ModuleListSize + ((ModuleList*)(pTemp))->NumberOfFunctions * FunctionListSize)
    ModuleCount++;
```

But i think it looks ugly. Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot overload operators for raw pointers - you would have to create a smart pointer class.

Comment: I'm not going to sugarcoat this: Overloading the increment operator(s) for custom pointer aliases will somehow bring *clarity* to your code? How about we old-school it and walk the structures in the loop, documenting what you're actually doing along the way rather than trying to misuse a  feature that won't do anything but obfuscate the code further (if it worked, which it won't).

Comment: You can improve readability by adding a method `void next()` or similar to `ModuleList`, and call that in your foor loop

Comment: Iterating over heterogeneous content with a single pointer, smart or raw, doesn't make sense.

Comment: Partially, I think the issue is with terminology. Had you called it an iterator, then we would all be happy. An iterator is an object that can be used like a pointer in certain ways, and if you follow that pattern I think you can do what you want with reasonable clarity.

Comment: Thanks for all of the answers, i decided to use a smart pointer class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ requires that your operator overloads take at least one operand of a "class type" or enumeration type. So, you can't overload operator for intrinsic/POD types and you need to wrap your struct with self-made smart-pointer class (as Neil proposed).